# How to iterate over rows given a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate over the rows with a specific column and putting only the value of that cell in an array. But when I do it, I got some weird structure.

I've tried different loops by it still come out the same way

```
s_num = []
file = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/vhim/Documents/Sunjeev/Sample_Data.xlsx')
info = pd.read_excel(file, "Sheet1", header=0, usecols=['so_number'])

for i in info.iterrows():
    s_num.append(i)
```

I want it to input only the cell value in my array but instead it inputs these values

```
(0, so_number    107819563
Name: 0, dtype: int64)
(1, so_number    347905182
Name: 1, dtype: int64)
(2, so_number    108161659
Name: 2, dtype: int64)
```

Comment: `for i in df["so_number"]:` ? (and please tell us what you are actually trying to do)

Comment: I can almost guarantee you do not need `iterrows` for this. Please provide a [mcve] with sample data and your expected output. My guess is `info['so_number'].to_list()`

Comment: Is not clear what your `info` is, but that is the worst way to make a list from a pandas column. Use `s_num = info['so_number'].tolist()` instead.

Comment: This said, a pandas column is a `Series`, it supports indexing and iteration. Not sure what you need to do, but high chance you don't even need to make a list from it.

Comment: I just want a list of so_number in my array. so it would be [107819563,347905182,108161659]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in df_temp["column1"]:
     print(i)
```

What you're getting is tuple of objects when you use `iterrows()` first item is row index and second item is the items in that column.

```py
for idx, column in df.iterrows():
    print(idx)
    print("----")
    print(column)
    print("====")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each row in pandas is essentially a tuple (a collection of column values so to say). So what you need to need to do is access the column in each row with something like

```
s_num.append(i['column_name'])
```

Look at [this] (https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-6fcd0170be9c) link for more info.